# Passing variable to awk in Linux script

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to write a script to get an input from user and then use that value to search test.csv file using awk and output to the screen. The content of test.csv is:

```
Name   ID
Rachel 123
Mark     321
Robert  461
```

For example I would like to get an input for ID# and using awk display the name associated with this ID.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter ID#";
read ID
echo $(awk -v val=$ID  '/val/{print}' /root/Desktop/test.csv
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here. Why on earth did you tag this c++?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first post. Put a wrong TAG to this question

Comment: check your sample code at http://shellcheck.net . It will flag syntax errors, and often provides good tips on how to correct problems (but it sometime takes a little time to understand the message). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

`/val/` matches the literal string "val". Instead, you can match the second word of each line with your variable using:

```
awk -v val="$ID"  '$2 == val {print}' /root/Desktop/test.csv
```

Note that this assumes that your input is the way you post it. If your `.csv` file is comma separated as they normally are, you would have to specify `-F ,`:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter id: " id
awk -F , -v val="$id"  '$2 == val { print $1 }' /root/Desktop/test.csv
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your answer. Yes, the input file are comma separated. Could you please write the complete echo command to display name associated with input ID?
Thank you